# How can I record a instance's create, edit, destroy in the convenient place?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Machine` model:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    type = models.ForeignKey(to=TypeModel)
    using = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ManyToManyField()
```

I want to record the `Machine` instance's `create`, `update`, and `destroy` records. 
So, I have a `MachineRecord` model:

```
class MachineRecord(models.Model):
    editor = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    machine = models.ForeignKey(to=Machine)
    old_content = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    new_content = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But, my problem is there are many place for creating and updating the `Machine` instance. Whether I can create the MachineRecord instance for Machine instance in a centralized place, such as in the Machine class?

I mean, if a instance create, update, destroy anywhere, I just pay attention to the centralized place for recording data.

---

**EDIT-01**

There many a saying re-write the Machine's save() method:

```
class Machine(models.Model):
  ...
  def save(*args, **kwargs):
    before_do_something()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    after_do_something()
```

but how about the `ManyToManyField`? I also want to record the groups brief in the 
`old_content` and `new_content`.

and the more important thing is the `editor` is the `request.user`(who call the UpdateAPI).

Comment: What's wrong with `Machine.save()` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how about there is a ManyToMany field in Machine?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You can check my EDIT-01.

Answer (score -1):

Django signals can be used for this.

You can register a listener on events like pre_save, post_save, post_delete and others.

You can even create your own signals.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/

The only downside might be that it can be hard to track a problem ( if occur ), especially if more people work on the project and are not aware of use of signals

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, i know. but i dont agree. I would not call it anti pattern. Even in the article it says it has its use. And this question is actually good example for signals - as I understood - he just wants to log an event. I would argue signal is good solution for this.

Comment: I don't say that signals are useless (quite on the contrary), just that using them for something you can already do in your model's methods - which is the case here - is an antipattern. The main point of signals is to provide hooks points for __other__ applications.  And I didn't wait for lincolnloop to post this article to find this out by myself - it's actually just plain common sense, if you want to do something special when one of _your_ models method is called, the simple obvious readable and maintainable solution is to override this method.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes , true. I agree with you. I mentioned in my answer that can be hard to track down a problem that's why it should not be used for stuff which has something to do with the model. However, i think that in this case, the "logging" mechanism he has can be taken out from the model ( if i understood that is just some kind of event logging - if not, and it is more related to the actual model, then it needs to be part of the model )

Comment: Reading the OP's code it's obviously "related to the actual model", not "just some kind of event logging". But anyway, I explained my point, no need to debate further as far as I'm concerned (and the OP might actually have a need for the m2mchanged signal FWIW, cf the edited question).